# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' in termux

Tags: python, android, import, termux

I am facing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' issue on Android termux terminal stimulator app.

The same code work without any additional configuration or installation on ubuntu except python.

Comment: Did you try installing requests? it was probably already installed in your ubuntu enviornment

Comment: yes, by command pip install requests getting SSL support error too